# UIView in custom UITableViewCell redraws when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I am adding an `UIView` inside my custom `UITableView` to draw more or less like an availability bar. I have two problems with it:

1.- The view only gets drawn when the new cells appear on screen not at launch time as you can see in the GIF below.

2.- When scrolling `tableView` several times the `UIView` on each cell is redrawn so they overlap with each other

[GIF](http://imgur.com/a/OCJiw)

**Code of UITableViewCell :**

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewcell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bikeStationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!


    override internal func awakeFromNib() {

    }
}
```

I think nothing is wrong there, it's simple. My problem I think comes with the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method. What I have so far is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CustomTableViewcell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewcell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 120/255, green: 120/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 0.5)

    // Dump the data into a single variable to shorten the code
    let stations = parsedData[indexPath.row]


    // Draw a rectangle on each progress bar depending on the availability of the bikes
    let availabilityGraph = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: cell.progressView.frame.minX, y: cell.progressView.frame.minY, width: CGFloat(Float(stations.freeBikes!) / (Float(stations.freeBikes!) + Float(stations.freeDocks!))) * cell.progressView.frame.width, height: cell.progressView.frame.height), cornerRadius: 0)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = availabilityGraph.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear().cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = cell.frame.height

    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 96/255, green: 96/255, blue: 96/255, alpha: 0.8).cgColor
    cell.progressView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    cell.bikeStationLabel.textColor = UIColor.white()
    cell.bikeStationLabel.text = stations.stationName!

    cell.distanceLabel.text = "100 m"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all give your layer specific name like this

```
shapeLayer.name = "ShapeLayer"
```

Now before adding it the `progressView` check that layer is not already added in the `progressView`, if added then just remove it.

```
if let sublayers = cell.progressView.layer.sublayers {
    for layer: CALayer in sublayers {
        if (layer.name == "ShapeLayer") {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            break
        }
    }
}
//Now add the layer to `progressView`
cell.progressView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: Just tried it. It crashes, classic optional unwrapping error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I've only added what you proposed, [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/UxD2r)

Comment: Almost done, now it doesn't redraw the cells as I scroll up/down as it did before. Now it draws the progress bar correctly but the specified height is not the one I specified, [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/6V6Bm)

Comment: I think you need to add this as another question with your new code and with more brief about your problem that will be helpful.

Comment: Also put the link of new question here i will check that.